# ZendFramework: Adding description to subform

Tags: forms, zend-framework, zend-form

I am completely new to ZF, so please excuse any stupidity on my part. I have the following bit in a ZendFramework, and I would like to add a description to it that displays on the subform, but I can't figure out how to do that.

```
$mySubForm = new SubForm(array(
     'legend'  => 'Title',
     'isArray' => false,
));

$this->addSubForms(
    array(
        'something' => $mySubForm;
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

To add the description, you can use the setDescription method:

```
$mySubForm->setDescription('MY MESSAGE');
```

If when you echo the Form, you don't see the description, add this line too:

```
$mySubForm->setDecorators(array('Description', 'FormElements', 'Form'));
```

Comment: wouldn't `$mySubForm->addDecorator('Description');` be more appropriate here?

Comment: No, you must specify all the decorators for the subform, see zend framework source at Zend/Form/SubForm.php @ 53 (zf 1.12)